# my thread loops exactly 43 times then throws an exception

Tags: java, audio

I cant figure it out. My code runs perfectly 43 times and then I get a `LineUnsupportedException` when the `Clip` object tries to reopen the line. Its a metronome so precise timing is important and I've got the code worked out to a mostly functional point. I create an `Clip[]` of `Clip` objects, there are as many as there are beats in a measure, I cycle through those in my while loop and each measure close and flush the clip and define a new `Clip[]` of Clip objects, if I don't close the line now and then and reset everything the audio will just stop playing, I'm not sure if the clips isActive() method returned false or what happened but that solution seemed to have fixed the problem until I started getting this exception, any thoughts on might be causing it?

Here is my output from the last working loop to the exception...

0

Tick...

COUNT:: 42

Loop completed in: 6

Beat Duration should be: 499

Time left to sleep: 493

1

Tick...

COUNT:: 43

unable to obtain a line

java: /build/buildd/openjdk-6-6b24-1.11.5/build/../pulseaudio/src/native/org_classpath_icedtea_pulseaudio_Stream.c:720: Java_org_classpath_icedtea_pulseaudio_Stream_native_1pa_1stream_1cork: Assertion `stream' failed.

and the two classes currently involved in this thread...

Ticker.java

```
package com.timer;

import java.io.IOException;

 import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class Ticker extends Thread {

private App app;

private String[] soundFiles;

private Ticker() {
}

public Ticker(App app) {
    this.app = app;
    soundFiles = new String[app.getBeatsPerMeasure()];
}

private AudioInputStream stream;

private Clip[] ticks;
AudioFormat format;
DataLine.Info dataLineInfo;

public String setFileNames() {
    for (int i = 0; i < app.getBeatsPerMeasure(); i++) {
        soundFiles[i] = "firstBeatCut.au";
    }
    return "";
}

public String loadArray(int... iArray) {
    if (iArray.length != app.getBeatsPerMeasure()) {
        return "Sorry there was an error.";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < iArray.length; i++) {
        iArray[i] = i;
        System.out.println(iArray[i]);
    }
    return "";
}

public void tick() {
    long difference, timeTaken, timeAllowedToSleep, before, after;
    long idealTime;

    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;

    ticks = new Clip[app.getBeatsPerMeasure()];

    while (app.isTicking()) {
        System.out.println("Tick...");

        before = System.nanoTime();

        try {

            stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass()
                    .getResource("./firstBeatCut.au"));

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (ticks[i] != null && ticks[i].isRunning()) {
            ticks[i].stop();
            if (ticks[i].isActive()) {
                ticks[i].close();
            }
        }

        count++;
        System.out.println("COUNT:: " + count);
        try {
            ticks[i] = (Clip) AudioSystem.getClip();
            if (!ticks[i].isOpen()) {
                ticks[i].open(stream);
            }
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ticks[i].setMicrosecondPosition(0);

        if (ticks[i].isOpen()) {
            ticks[i].setMicrosecondPosition(0L);
            ticks[i].start();
        } else {
            try {
                ticks[i].open(stream);
            } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ticks[i].setMicrosecondPosition(0);
            ticks[i].start();
        }

        idealTime = app.calculateSleep(app.getBPM())
                - ticks[i].getMicrosecondLength();

        after = System.nanoTime();

        timeTaken = (after - before);
        difference = (idealTime - timeTaken);
        System.out.println("Loop completed in: " + (timeTaken / 1000000L)
                + "\nBeat Duration should be: " + (idealTime / 1000000L)
                + "\nTime left to sleep: " + (difference / 1000000L));

        timeAllowedToSleep = difference;

        if (timeAllowedToSleep > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(timeAllowedToSleep / 1000000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(i);

        stopTick(ticks[i], ++i);
        if (i == app.getBeatsPerMeasure()) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}

public void closeTick(Clip tick) {
    tick.close();
}

public void stopTick(Clip tick, int index) {
    tick.stop();
    if (index == 4) {
        closeTick(tick);

        try {
            tick = AudioSystem.getClip();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void play(Clip tick) {
    tick.setMicrosecondPosition(0L);
    tick.start();
}

public long calculateTimeAllowedToSleep(long sTime, long time) {
    long diff = time - sTime;
    long timeToSleep;
    long ssTime = 60000 / 120;
    timeToSleep = ssTime - diff;
    return timeToSleep;

}

}
```

ActionHandler.java

```
package com.timer;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener, ChangeListener {

private App app;
Ticker ticker;
Thread t1;
private int beatsInMeasure;
private boolean ticking;

public ActionHandler(final App app) {
    this.app = app;
    this.ticker = new Ticker(app);
    beatsInMeasure = app.getTimeSignature()[0];
    ticking = app.isTicking();
    ticker.loadArray(0,1,2,3);
}

private Runnable doTick = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (app.isTicking()) {

            ticker.tick();

        }
    }
};

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
    if (b == app.getBtnStart()) {
        if (b.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Start")) {
            app.setStartText("Stop");
            app.resetEnabled(false);
            ticker.setFileNames();
            app.setTicking(true);
            t1 = new Thread(doTick);
            t1.start();
        } else {
            app.setStartText("Start");
            app.resetEnabled(true);
            app.setTicking(false);
            app.setTicking(false);
            try {
                t1.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else if (b == app.getBtnReset()) {
        app.reset();
    }
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    JSpinner sp = (JSpinner) e.getSource();
    SpinnerNumberModel model = app.getModel();
    if (sp.getValue() != null) {
        app.calculateSleep(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(
                sp.getModel().getValue()).toString()));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide your code?

Comment: Show the code and the exception...

Comment: I was afraid of that, okay I'm gonna have to clean it up a little first. I've been debugging it so there's all kinds of random stuff all over the place and I'm not going to make you sift through it so I'll post it in a few minutes.

Comment: Sounds like `AnswerToUniverseOverflowException`. Please create as short as possible code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: That's kind of an "off by one"-error since you exceeded the answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything by one when you reach 43.

Comment: in[] of clip object. This question is troll.

Comment: I don't see it, but I'll search for it in an editor. But doesn't that raise even more questions? Why does it even work in the first place if its the wrong data type? I better go find out where this is and see when its getting called.

Comment: The search in Eclipse and Geany both returned nothing, where do you see that?

Comment: @KevinBigler it is stated in your question `I create an int[] of Clip objects`.

Comment: Oh that makes more sense, okay then back to the initial question, I'll edit that.

Comment: I tried adding `count < app.getBeatsPerMeasure() * 4` to the while loop in the tick method so it would break out of it every 16 loops (with the current time signature) and then get called again from the original thread and sure enough on the 3rd time around it looped 11 times then I got the same exception. 16+16+11=43, I'm really stumped, could it be a data issue? Maybe I'm using up all my lines in the `AudioSystem`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open a line close it as soon as you're done with it every time. i removed the if statement from the stop method in Ticker and it works perfectly. I'm going to sleep, thanks to everyone who commented.